# Différence de registre et position de l'adverbe

Tags: sens, adverbes, ordre-des-mots, constructions

- *Nous en avons longtemps parlé*.
- *Nous en avons parlé longtemps*.

Y a-t-il une différence de registre entre les deux, si légère soit-elle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il me semble que les registres de langage des deux phrases sont équivalents, la position de l'adverbe n'y change rien.

On rencontre en revanche plus souvent la forme :

- Nous en avons **longuement** parlé.

D'une manière générale, la position de l'adverbe (avant ou après le verbe) apporte parfois une nuance de sens, rarement de registre.

Answer (score 6):

Personnellement j'y vois une différence de sens, pas une différence de registre.

*Nous en avons longtemps parlé*, signifierait (selon moi) que le sujet a été maintes fois abordé au cours d'une période de temps assez longue. *Nous en avons parlé longtemps* ferait plutôt référence à une discussion particulière qui aurait duré longtemps, sans être interrompue.

(Ce n'est qu'une impression, je ne sais pas comment confirmer ou infirmer cette hypothèse.)

Answer (score 3):

Aucune des deux constructions n'appartient au registre familier, mais je perçois quand même une différence : la première me semble un tout petit peu plus soutenue que la seconde. En revanche, je ne saurais pas expliquer pourquoi (peut-être parce que ça ressemble à une inversion poétique ?).

Comment: Oui, les phrases n'appartient au registre familier mais je n'ai pas pu créer la bonne étiquette (la simple catégorie «registre») à cause de ma réputation faible.

Comment: Ce n'est pas du registre *familier*, mais plutôt du registre *courant*.